# Add 2 git repos in system

Tags: git, aws-codecommit, credential-manager

I am using aws code commit which uses git for code.
I have created 2 repos say for eg repoA and repoB.
Every time when i want to use either of these repos i have to remove one from credential manager then apply my credentials and then perform action.
I am trying to globally set both the repos in credential manager but failed to do so.
Please help me with this.

Comment: you can use remote and origin as 2 different repos. NOt really a great thing but your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to register two different credentials for a same remote server.
Simply change the remote URL in order to include your username:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote set-url  https://<myUsername1>@<aws-server>/me/myrepo
```

That way, you would cache a credentials for the URL `<myUsername1>@<aws-server>` instead of just `<aws-server>`